Issue in backtracking while creating combinations of a list of size k
def combination(n,k):

    combi=[]
    
    def backtrack(start,comb):
        print(comb)
        if len(comb)==k:
            combi.append(comb.copy())
            return 
            
        for i in range(start,n+1):
            # print(i)
            cur=[i]
            backtrack(i+1,comb+cur)
            comb.pop()
            print("comb after",comb)
    backtrack(1,[])
    return combi

combination(4,3)

I am getting IndexError: pop from empty list.
When I printed comb to identify error, I am getting this:
1
[]
i is 1
2
[1]
i is 2
3
[1, 2]
i is 3
4
[1, 2, 3]
comb after [1]
i is 4
5
[1, 4]
comb after []
comb after []
i is 3
4
[3]
i is 4
5
[3, 4]
comb after []



Why is my code popping 2 and 3 both when it should only pop 3 after getting [1,2,3].why isnt it popping only 3. What am I doing wrong?

Please give your question a better title so anyone else searching for the same problem can find the answers

comb is indeed empty. You never appended anything to it.
The misunderstanding probably comes from the argument you build for the recursive call:
        backtrack(i+1,comb+cur)

...but that doesn't modify comb. That just creates a new list that has one more element, and which in the recursive execution of the function is assigned to a local name that happens also be comb. But that is a distinct variable, and local to that execution only. When backtrack returns, you still have the same comb as before doing comb+cur.
Conclusion, you don't need to pop anything. What you added with +cur only affects what the recursive execution sees; it does not affect the comb variable in the current execution of the function.
Alternative
You could compare this with a version of the code where the call of pop() makes sense:
    comb.append(i)  # Now we DO mutate `comb` here
    backtrack(i+1,comb)
    comb.pop()  # ... and need to revert that change.


This helped,thankyou soo much

Good to hear! Now you can mark one answer as accepted if you wish.

With the first fix, there's also no reason to call copy().

When you are using comb + cur you are creating a new list. So when comb.pop() is called it pops from original comb list. Here is the fix
def combination(n, k):
    combi = []
    
    def backtrack(start, comb):
        # print(comb)
        if len(comb) == k:
            combi.append(comb.copy())
            return
        
        for i in range(start, n + 1):
            comb.append(i)
            backtrack(i + 1, comb)
            comb.pop()
            # print(f"comb after: {comb}")
    
    backtrack(1, [])
    return combi

print(combination(4, 3))

